# Operaciones con incógnitas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy empezando con *Python* y he hecho un código para que haga los *binomios de Newton* (ej: (2+9)<sup>9</sup>) si le inserto los dos terminos y la potencia.

Este és el código:

```
from math import *

def combinacio(n,k):
    return int(factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)))

potencia = int(input("Inserta la potencia de el binomi: "))
yo = int(input("Inserta el primer terme: "))
xo =  int(input("Inserta el segon terme: "))
fila_preguntada = potencia

def pascal(files):
    resultat = []
    #aquí es on es la llista on es guarda el resultat
    for count in range(files):
        #conta les integres de 0 fins a files-1 i per cada loop dona el valor de count, ex:nº files = 3, fa un loop pel num 0, i pel 1 i el 2
        fila = []
        #una altra llista
        for element in range(count+1):
        #conta les integres de 0 fins a count+1 i ho guarda com a valor de element, ex: files = 3, 1r loop on count és 0, aqui li suma 1, llavors li dona que element és 0, pel 2n loop, element es 1, 3r loop 2
            fila.append(combinacio(count,element))
            #li afageix a la fila la combinacio de count i element, ex: count= 0, element = 0, count = 1, element = 1,count= 2, element = 2, llavors fila seria [1,2,1]
    resultat.append(fila)
    #afageix el resultat de fila a resultat
    return resultat

def agafar_la_llista():
    for fila in pascal(fila_preguntada):
    #busca la variable fila fent la variable pascal amb l'argument fila_preguntada.
        return fila

def fer_la_potencia_de_X():
    llista_x = []
    for x in range(potencia):
        xp = xo**x
        llista_x.append(xp)
    return llista_x

def fer_la_potencia_de_Y():
    llista_y = []
    for y in range((potencia-1),-1,-1 ):
        yp = yo**y
        llista_y.append(yp)
    return llista_y

def resposta_final():
    pascal = agafar_la_llista()
    X = fer_la_potencia_de_X()
    Y = fer_la_potencia_de_Y()
    resultat_final = []
    for m in range(potencia):
        k = pascal[m] * X[m] * Y[m]
        resultat_final.append(k)
    print (resultat_final)

resposta_final()
```

Entonces este codigo me hace una lista con los términos en orden, el problema es que no puedo insertar incógnitas en `yo` o `xo` (1r y 2do término) ya que no se pueden pasar a integral para hacer operaciones, tampoco puedo quitar el `int()` ya que con strings no puedo elevar por ejemplo x<sup>5</sup>, sino que me devolveria `"xxxxx"`.

Comment: No es estrictamente necesario que captures las variables "yo" y "xo" como enteros. Puedes mantenerlos como cadenas, y luego al momento de usarlas, como en tu ejemplo, interpretarlas: int(X)**5.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, voy a buscar que es una cadena.

Comment: Cadena es un dato tipo String, perdon, suelo usar los nombres de las cosas en español.

Comment: Vale, creo que ya entendido lo que quieres decir, pero al hacer int(xo)**2 si xo = "x" <- simulando el input , me da: """ ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x' """. Entonces como puedo hacer operaciones con incognitas?

Comment: Claro, lo que dices es correcto. No puedes hacer automáticamente una operación. Desconozco si existe algún módulo específico para eso. ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de las operacións con incógnitas que quieres hacer?

Comment: __Sí, un ejemplo seria (x+3)**3, lo cual tendria que dar [x**2, 6x, 9]. Para hacer llegar hasta aqui, tendria que elevar la x primero a la 2, despues a la 1 y finalmente a la 0, es decir, [(combinación)*x**2 * 3**0, (combinación)*x**1 * 3**1, (combinación) * x**0 * 3 ** 2]__ ( he puesto en texto en negrita para que no interprete los asteriscos como negrita)

Comment: Entonces aquí esta el problema, no puedo hacer operaciones con x como si fuera un numero.

Comment: Encontré un módulo (Sympy) para trabajar con polinomios: http://www.pythondiario.com/2017/09/operaciones-con-polinomios-en-python.html y https://pypi.org/project/sympy/.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que te están pidiendo que crees una nueva clase:

```
class Termino:
    def __init__(self, letra=[x], coeff=1, potencia=[1]):
        self.letra = letra
        self.coeff = coeff
        self.potencia = potencia

    def mostrar(self):
        if coeff == 0:
            print("0")
        elif potencia == 0:
            print("1")
        elif (coeff=1 and potencia=1):
            print(letra, sep='')
        elif coeff == 1:
            print(letra, "^",potencia, sep='')
        elif potencia == 1:
            print(coeff, letra, "^",sep='')
        else:
            print(coeff, letra, "^",potencia, sep='')

    def __add__(self, other):
        if ((self.letra =! other.letra) or (self.potencia =! other.potencia)):
            return [self, other]
        else:
            return Termino(self.letra, self.coeff+other.coeff, self.potencia)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if (self.letra =! other.letra):
            return Termino(self.letra+other.letra, self.coeff*other.coeff, [self.potencia, other.potencia])
        else:
            return Termino(self.letra, self.coeff*other.coeff, [self.potencia*other.potencia])
```

Y así hasta que **tengas definidas todas las operaciones según las propiedades de los polinomios**, y después podrás operar con los objetos de ese tipo como más te convenga.

Mis disculpas por no dar una respuesta completa pero yo también estoy comenzando. Espero que te sirva como punto de partida.